# Color Scale using two pieces of information

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula, ms-office

I need to make a color scale using two pieces of information. I have included a picture below for reference.

What I want need to do is match input a level (cell F3) with the model levels (cell A3:A4).

Then I need to compare my input score (cell G3) with the low, mid, hi scores on the model (cell B3:D4).

Then I need to highlight my score (cell G3) with the corresponding color. Any advice is much appreciate!

[image]

Comment: You will need 3 rules in Conditional Formatting.  A formula by itself cannot change the format of itself or any other cell.

Comment: @KobyDouek I have two inputs, MY LEVEL and MY SCORE, and I need to compare to the model. I need MY LEVEL to dictate which row I am on on the model then MY SCORE to dictate which Column/Cell I am in on the model. Then I need to extract the color of the model cell. I hope that clarified my questions. I apologize for the wordiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a slight adjustment to your table.  Instead of a range like `29-40` just put the lower limit `29`:

[image]

Then create three rules:

Red

```
=MATCH(G3,INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F3,A:A,0),0))=1
```

Yellow

```
=MATCH(G3,INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F3,A:A,0),0))=2
```

Green

```
=MATCH(G3,INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F3,A:A,0),0))=3
```

[image]

Comment: Say someone mistypes and puts 'o' in F3 instead of `M`.  This way it would remain white and flag that there is an issue.  I am all for fewer rules but for me to have a flag that something is not correct is better. @pnuts